# In the Forgiveness Petition of the Amidah, How Should One Strike the Chest?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, parts-of-the-body, chol-weekday

When praying the *Amidah*, each Siddur I own mentions striking the chest at key points. However, neither tells how. I tend to make a loose fist and strike the left breast with a moderate force (not painful). Is this the proper manner?

**How should I "strike the chest" in the Forgiveness Petition of the Amidah?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Kehot Annotated Siddur](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16091&st=&pgnum=108&hilite=) says (p. 47):

> On days when Tachnun is said, gently strike the left side of your chest (over the heart) with a closed fist at the words חטאנו and פעשנו.

Comment: @Yishai "On days when Tachnun is said" is confusing to me.  Don't we still clop our chest in the month of Nissan and on Rosh Hodesh?  That aside, the procedure description is spot on.

Comment: @Mike, the chabad custom is only when tachnun is said. Others may not distinguish.

Comment: @Yishai, Minhagei Ashkenaz uPolin/Lita say that we always strike the chest at chatanu and pashanu.