# How should a person wearing t'fillin on his right hand strike his left chest at 'oshamnu'

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, tefilin, chol-weekday, handedness

> On days when Tachnun is said, gently strike the left side of your chest (over the heart) with a closed fist at the words חטאנו and פעשנו. (from [Kehot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37684))

How should a left handed person wearing t'fillin on his right hand strike his chest? Should he use his left hand, or the right one even though he is wearing t'fillin on it?

Comment: Why do you suspect tefillin would matter?

Comment: the same as it matters regarding tachnum

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v29/mj_v29i30.html) it quotes in the name of Kuntres Ish Itair 51, that it is dependent upon anatomy, which means a left handed person uses the right hand. He is talking about "Ashamnu" which only some Nusachos ever say with Tefillin on, so it isn't explicit that Tefillin doesn't change the consideration.

[Here](http://www.shtaygen.co.il/?CategoryID=1027&ArticleID=6900) it specifically addresses Slach Lanu (#27) and says that the right hand is used. The top of the page indicates that most of the rulings there follow the *p'sak* of R' Chaim Kanievsky. T'fillin are not mentioned explicitly.

Although Tefillin are not explicitly mentioned it would be quite an oversight to not mention it, as that is almost always said (by men) with Tefillin on, and I have observed lefties doing just that.

Comment: Just because the heart is on the left side doesn't mean you have to hit it with the right hand.

Answer (score 0):

[What side does someone with Situs inversus bang](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44765/what-side-does-someone-with-situs-inversus-bang/46054#46054)

Since it is an explicit statement to bang the left side of the chest with the right hand, it should not matter whether or not one is wearing teffilin on the right hand.