# Should the Chazzan strike his chest during the repetition of the Amidah

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, parts-of-the-body

If one is serving as the *shaliach tzibur*, should he strike his chest during the repetition of the *amidah* during the reading of the paragraph of *selach lanu*, as an individual dues during the silent recitation?

[related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37683/in-the-forgiveness-petition-of-the-amidah-how-should-one-strike-the-chest/37684#37684)

Comment: I see no reason why he shouldn't. Do you? What is it? Without any such motivation this is a bad question post since the answer appears obvious. The Chazzan takes steps, bows etc. I've never seen a Siddur give different instructions in this regard. What is driving you to wonder about this?

Comment: http://www.chabad.org.il/Questions/Index.asp?SubjectID=5&RabbiID=44&search=%E4%EB%E0%E4+%F2%EC+%E4%EC%E1+%E1%E7%E6%F8%FA&CategoryID=68 seems to imply that MB 115:1 says the leader should not bang in his repetition. In fact, though, MB 115:1 says no such thing AFAICT. Nonetheless, that page's citation of the last Lubavitcher rebbe's practice (viz, that he did bang) _may_ be correct....